# PHP preg_match iteration

Tags: php

I have an

```
array() {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "id1"
  [1] =>
  string(14) "Gucci"
  [2] =>
  string(1) "id1"
  [3] =>
  string(24) "bag1"
  [4] =>
  string(4) "id2"
  [5] =>
  string(14) "Gucci"
  [6] =>
  string(4) "id2"
  [7] =>
  string(25) "Gucci bag2"
  [8] =>
  string(4) "id3"
  [9] =>
  string(14) "Gucci"
  [10] =>
  string(4) "id3"
  [11] =>
  string(27) "bag3"
```

..more

the key 0, 2, 4, ...are the id
the key 1, 5 .. are the brand
the key 3, 6 are the name

i want to loop trough the array to check if $array[1] is in $array[3], and then $array[5] is in $array[7]

how can i have the iteration of

```
if (preg_match("/$array[$i+1]/i", "$array[$i+3]")) {
        echo "$array[$i]";
    } else {
        echo $array[$i+1] . ' ' . $array[$i+3];
   }
```

Thank you